# Echo data from database in each times get

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I send three times values `1` & `2` & `3` by `jquery.serialize()` for `$hotel_id` in PHP, now i want get in the each times from send, data linked with `$hotel_id`(like: `1` or `2` or `3`) from database. but in the following code i just get data that linked to last `$hotel_id`(`3`).

I want as:

> **First**: get data linked with `1` and echo they in `json_encode`
>   **Second**: (next 2) get data linked with `2` and echo they in
>   `json_encode`
>  **Third**: (next 3)get data linked with `3` and echo
>   they in `json_encode`
> ...

This is output `serialize()` from jQuery code:

```
hotel_id=1&hotel_id=2&hotel_id=3
```

This is my php code:

```
$hotel_id = $this->input->post('hotel_id');
$query_r  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE id LIKE '$hotel_id' ORDER BY id desc");
$data     = array();
foreach ($query_r->result() as $row) {
    $data_s  = json_decode($row->service, true);
    $data_rp = json_decode($row->address, true);
    $data[]  = array(
        'name' => $row->name,
        'star_type' => $row->star . '-' . $row->type,
        'site' => $row->site,
        'service' => $data_s,
        'address' => $row->address
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

How do i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass in the same argument three times. It will only see the final parameter of hotel_id and so you just get number 3. PHP does allow for passing Arrays by naming the parameter with [] at the end like hotel_id[]=1&hotel_id[]=2, etc and then you can get the array of values in php. That means your value of $hotel_id would be an array of values instead of a single value. Since it is an array you would need to implode the array with a comma to use in your SQL:

```
$hotel_id = implode(',', $this->input->post('hotel_id'));
```

Now $hotel_id will look like '1,2,3';

Now your SQL will need to change to:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE id IN ($hotel_id) ORDER BY id desc
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did not need to change in `$query_r` and `foreach`? and this have error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'...`

Comment: If you implode the hotel_ids into one variable then your script will behave as you intended (I didn't test it). Note that I haven't validated any of the code in your foreach, I've just explained the issue with the hotel_id and the sql query.

Comment: I would suggest adding debugging elements to analyze your script. This will help you understand what's going on in PHP at each step of the process. For example, what is the value of $hotel_id after imploding the post? (print_r($hotel_id);)

Comment: Ok, but this `$hotel_id = '1,2,3';` not work for query and foreach.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer to reflect the necessary SQL change using the IN clause.